# JQuery autocomplete add item to rendered dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I was wondering is there is any way to append a new item in an already rendered dropdown autocomplete menu.

What I'm trying to do is to get a fixed number of results from the server with ajax and show a "Show More..." link at the end. If selected, this link should start another ajax query and load more items in the same dropdown.

Makes any sense? I'm also not sure if I'm overthinking it and there is an easier way to perform the same task.

**EDIT 1**

The code I currently have is something similar to this one:

> ```
> $(function () {
>         $("#srchOperator").autocomplete({
>             source: function (request, response) {
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: "someURL",
>                     type: "POST",
>                     dataType: "JSON",
>                     data: JSON.stringify(somePostData),
>                     success: function (data) {
>                         response($.map(data), function(item) {
>                             return {
>                                 label: item.fields['op'],
>                                 id: item._id
>                             }
>                         });
>                         var totalResults = data.total
>                         if (totalResults - 10 > 0) {
>                             $('.ui-autocomplete').append('<li ' +
>                                     'class=ui-menu-item><a ' +
>                                     'href="#">(' + (totalResults - 10) +
>                                     ' more...)</a></li>');
>                         }
>                     },
>                 });
>             },
>             minLength: 2,
>         })
>     });
> ```

The first ajax call will retrieve only 10 elements and the "more" link should perform an ajax call that appends items to the dropdown on its callback.

Comment: if you could, would you please post a snipit of your code

Comment: I added a little piece of code. I hope it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, you could hide the rest using CSS.

```
.ui-autocomplete li:nth-of-type(1n+10) {
   display: none;
}

.ui-autocomplete li.moreResults {
   display: block;
}
```

The Javascript for the link would look like:

```
$('.moreResults').click(function(){
   $('.ui-autocomplete li').show();
});
```

Please note that I added a class for the link to differentiate from regular items. If the link is created after you declare this function, you need to use the on function like:

```
$(document).on('click','.moreResults',function(){
   $('.ui-autocomplete li').show();
});
```

This should do the trick. On a side note, I personally would restructure it to only grab the results you need initially as it will load faster and load the next set when you click more.

Comment: The results are loaded from elasticsearch. What I'm trying to do is to load the first 10 autocomplete results when typing and load the others when clicking the link (with another ajax call). I don't have all the items to show a few and just hide the others.